# TortoiseSVN error mismatched tag

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm new to this SVN stuff. The thing is, I am part of a development team and we need to access the same file. To do so we have a repository server. My superior has given me the FTP username and password saying that it is the same for the SVN repository. This have been bugging me for quite some days now. Every time I tried to checkout the files I get the same error. How do I fix this error?

```
Error: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://www.example.org'  //<== Is this my error?
Error: The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at
Error:  line 33: mismatched tag (http://www.example.org)
```

I just use [PuTTY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PuTTY) to commit and SFTP to ul/dl. zzz.

Comment: It sounds like you should just ask your superior to help you fix the problem...

Comment: Do u have the address of your file server??

Comment: yes, i can access the file server in ftp

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth - He is not using tortoisesvn or even windows. plus he is halfway around the world >.<

Answer (score 0):

1. Checkout not file, but full directory of file
2. Try checkout with CLI-client
3. If you still get the same error, write to superior

> "SVN-repository server is badly misconfigured - XSLT-template, used in
>   SVNIndexXSLT directive isn't valid"

Answer (score 0):

It's 99.99999% certainty that your repository is NOT located at http://www.mydomain.com
So if this is really in the error (and not something that you edited for privacy and didn't tell us), then you have not configured your SVN client properly.